# Download pdf to be linked with member registration

Tags: joomla-2.5, extensions, download

We wish to give link to full paper download on the article page displaying abstract.

We plan to provide 3 fields namely Name,email-id,member no with submit button. Once the user fills the information his name should be registered as a member and the pdf of concerned paper should get downloaded on users machine.
How this functionality can be incorporated ?

Comment: you can use a form component or build a custom form. Not sure how is this going to work without the submit button. Submit is essential, otherwise how it is going to know that the user has entered and finished what he wants to put in the form? Search for Joomla form builders in joomla extensions

Comment: I believe that they can suggest that on blur - field is filled. So on blur check if all fields have values - if yes - make them readonly and send registration data via ajax. on ajax response link pdf download

Comment: @Alexandr, yes technically it can be on blur or other events, but a javascript that will submit without the user first has confirmed he is ready and wants to submit? Bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using [RS Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/rsform-pro) Pro. You build the form (a simple form), and then you create a script in the "On Submit" event of the form that will automatically create create a user and that will automatically cause the PDF to be downloaded on the user's machine (or course, with the user's permission).

There are some extensions that can do that, but they need some modifications, including Membership Pro and DocMan.